# Unlock windows using information from active directory

Tags: .net, c

How to log on into PC from sleep when the PC required password to log on it.
Can I create windows service to automatically enter the password and log in into the PC when it wake up from sleep.

From what I read, It required custom Windows Credential to automatically log on into the PC if the PC have password.

Can I request the example of custom Windows Credential.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log in after sleep/hibernate without entering a password, just change your power settings:

> https://superuser.com/questions/631286/how-to-automatically-log-in-after-sleep
>
> Go to Control Panel, locate the "Power Settings" and double-click.
>   There you should find an "Advanced" tab where you will see a checkbox
>   "Ask for a password after waking up from sleep" or similar.
>
> (Un)Check it, save, and you should be set.

Comment: I want to log in after sleep/hibernate by automatically entering the password